# Make an element overlap others when viewport runs out of room

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the blue square that will contain things adding up to `800px`.

I want the red square to always be fully visible. That is when you narrow the viewport, the red square should overlap the blue square, and not disappear on the right like it does actually.

How can I achieve that?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  height: 80px;
}

.should-be-overlapped {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  background: blue;
}

.always-full-width {
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="should-be-overlapped"></div>
  <div class="always-full-width"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish that, there is mainly 2 ways.

Either add a wrapper around the blue (which I recommend).

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJxzgb)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

div {
  height: 80px;
}

.wrapper {
   flex: 1;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.should-be-overlapped {
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 800px;
   background: blue;
}

.always-full-width {
  flex: 0 0 400px;
  background: red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="should-be-overlapped">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="always-full-width">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or use `position: absolute`.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RxXZMP)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  height: 80px;
}

.should-be-overlapped {
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 800px;
   background: blue;
}

.always-full-width {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;  
}
```

```html
.<div class="container">
  <div class="should-be-overlapped">
  </div>
  <div class="always-full-width">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have the blue square that will contain things adding up to 800px.

Then you should do it with the `flex: 0 1 800px`, which will *enable* it to *shrink*:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  height: 80px;
}

.should-be-overlapped {
  /*min-width: 800px;*/
  flex: 0 1 800px; /* doesn't grow but shrinks, initial width set to 800px (this is also its "max-width") */
  background: blue;
  word-break: break-all; /* for longer unbreakable strings, just for demo */
}

.always-full-width {
  /*width: 400px;*/
  flex: 0 0 400px; /* since you're using flexbox, doesn't grow nor shrink, initial width set to 400px (fixed) */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="should-be-overlapped">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="always-full-width"></div>
</div>
```